# How do you get search capability similar to Spotlight or iTunes?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, search, spotlight

I have an NSTableView that contains a few columns that are populated with data.  How do I set up a search bar that can filter the rows based on the content of a specific column?  I am looking for the type of thing that is done with Spotlight in the Finder or the search bar in iTunes that can filter songs by metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can your data source be managed by NSArrayController?

There are 2 [standard](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Tasks/filtering.html) approaches.  The first (pre-Tiger) technique is to subclass NSArrayController, overriding arrangeObjects.  The second (post-Tiger) is to bind NSSearchField's predicates to the NSArrayController's filterPredicate.  In either case, bind your view properties to the controller's `arrangedObject` key (e.g. bind the "name" NSTableColumn to the controller's `arrangedObjects.name` key and bind the NSTableView's content to `arrangedObjects`).  You might want to read up on [writing predicates](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html).

Comment: Keep in mind you don't need to use bindings to use NSPredicate, it works just as well on a plain NSArray object if you're using datasource methods to populate your table view.

Answer (score 3):

"Spotlight" capability is actually given to you with the SearchKit API, although for a simple case like what you're describing NSPredicate would probably be a better choice. If anyone's interested though, I wrote a SearchKit presentation for CocoaHeads you can [take a look at here](http://blog.mbcharbonneau.com/2009/02/26/searchkit-example-project/).